# Get index and value of non-NA list element

Tags: r, list, subset, na

Take a list like `as.list(rep(c(NA, 4, NA), times = c(5, 1, 2)))` i.e.

```
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] NA

[[4]]
[1] NA

[[5]]
[1] NA

[[6]] # index of non-NA list element, 6
[1] 4 # ...and its corresponding value, 4 

[[7]]
[1] NA

[[8]]
[1] NA
```

I want to extract the index of the non-NA element (here: 6), and its corresponding value (here: 4). Is there any idiomatic way to get these two numbers?

Comment: Is each list element always a vector of length 1?

Comment: @Henrik I'm happy to say yes.

Comment: OK, then maybe `cbind(ix <- which(!is.na(l)), l[[ix]])` (where individual parts already used in other answers).

Comment: @Henrik, Even if that works now it could potentially fail in the future since arguments are not guaranteed to be evaluated in order.  To be safe the `ix<- ...` part should be made a separate statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Base R** Assuming that the list L contains only scalars and NA's this returns a 2 column matrix with one row for each set of xy coordinates and an attribute recording which positions were omitted.

Omit the `x=` and `y=` if you don't want the column names.  If you don't want the attribute recording the positions of the NA's append `[,]` to the end of the line. If you know that there is only one scalar you might want to wrap it in `c(...)` to produce a 2 element vector.  If you prefer data frame output replace `cbind` with `data.frame`.

```
na.omit(cbind(x = seq_along(L), y = unlist(L)))
```

**2) tidyverse** or using the tidyverse

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

drop_na(enframe(unlist(L)))
```

**2a)** which could alternately be written using pipes like this:

```
L %>% unlist %>% enframe %>% drop_na
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is elegant enough but works;

```
mylist <- as.list(rep(c(NA, 4, NA), times = c(5, 1, 2)))

x <- (1:length(mylist))[!sapply(mylist,is.na)]
y <- mylist[[x]]

coor <- c(x,y)

coor
```

**output;**

```
6 4
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find index of non NA list == 6 to get `x`
2. Remove all list elements with NA  to get `y`

```
my_list <- as.list(rep(c(NA, 4, NA), times = c(5, 1, 2)))


x <- which(!is.na(my_list))
y <- unlist(Filter(function(a) any(!is.na(a)), my_list))
coordinate <- c(x,y)
coordinate
```

```
> coordinate
[1] 6 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `stack`

```
na.omit(stack(setNames(L, seq_along(L))))
  values ind
6      4   6
```